# Ubuntu 20.04 can't read my SDXC card 128Gb (Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1)

Tags: mount, 20.04, sd-card

I'm using a USB card reader Hama (has several slots). I'm able to open an SDHC card 16Gb with the card reader, Ubuntu can mount it. I'm able to open a microSDXC card 128Gb with my another USB microSD card reader (has only one slot). But when I'm trying to insert the 128Gb SDXC into the Hama card reader, I get nothing except these repeated messages from the kernel:

```
[ 1884.545896] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 1884.569608] sd 6:0:0:2: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1884.569616] sd 6:0:0:2: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0e ef f6 00 00 00 f8 00
[ 1884.926892] sd 6:0:0:2: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1884.926898] sd 6:0:0:2: [sdd] tag#0 Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
[ 1884.926904] sd 6:0:0:2: [sdd] tag#0 Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
[ 1884.926909] sd 6:0:0:2: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0e ef f7 00 00 00 80 00
[ 1884.927254] sd 6:0:0:2: [sdd] tag#0 device offline or changed
[ 1884.927277] sd 6:0:0:2: [sdd] tag#0 device offline or changed
[ 1884.927284] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 31321792, async page read
[ 1884.961311]  sdd: sdd1
[ 1885.193853] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 1885.575674] sd 6:0:0:2: [sdd] tag#0 device offline or changed
[ 1885.575727] sd 6:0:0:2: [sdd] tag#0 device offline or changed
[ 1885.575738] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd1, logical block 31321792, async page read
[ 1885.608919]  sdd: sdd1
```

I can't find any clue to solve this problem. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd say the reader is not capable of reading cards of that size. There is a limit (I think it is 64GB) above which older readers don't recognize the card.

Comment: The reader is capable of reading this card on Windows. So, it is not it. I saw another post (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243163/sdxc-card-and-usb-3-harddrive-wont-mount-in-ubuntu-20-04-but-do-in-ubuntu-18-0). Someone tried an SDXC card on Ubuntu 18.04, and it worked.

Comment: Have you tried in all different USB slots of the computer? And in other computers? -- Some card readers are not compatible with all USB hardware and drivers in the computers. I have a HAMA USB 3 card reader, that works for reading and writing data. But I cannot boot via it. I have some other USB card readers, that are happy to allow booting.